# set UIPIckerView height width dynamically in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

I want to set `UIPIckerView` `height` `width` dynamically in `iphone`.please give me idea for it.

Comment: How do you want to resize, is there any constraints?

Comment: I want to set height = 50 and width= 50 but it does not change its size.

Comment: Check my answer. There is a default size for pickerView you cannot reduce the height below that limit.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you can change dynamically height and width of only `UIPickerView` Not `UidatePicker` so go with this code you will find out the way :-

```
    UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    CGSize ps = [picker sizeThatFits: CGSizeZero];
    picker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, ps.width, ps.height + 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to change the frame, check your `autoLayout` for constant width. If you are not using autoLayout disable it. By default `pickerView` has `flexibleWidth` `resizingMask`. 
.

You can adjust the width, but height is restricted to not less than `162.0f`. Even if you try it won't resize. You will get following error **`invalid height value 50.0 pinned to 162.0`**